# Apache2 and solr with SSL using proxypass

Tags: apache, ssl, solr, proxypass

I am trying to setup a subdomain on my Apache2 vhosts that will answer to solr requests on port 443.

I setup my solr 8.1.1 and it is reacheable with my ip at port 8984, now I need it to be available as https://solr.mydomain.org, so I tryed to setup a vhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName solr.mydomain.org
Redirect permanent /secure https://solr.mydomain.org
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName solr.mydomain.org
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.solr.log
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8984/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8984/
 </VirtualHost>
```

after I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214825/apache-solr-access-solr-server-by-https-domain-name) answer (and notes) and other online guides.

I have also installed all the mods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39918865/apache-webserver-reverseproxy-to-serve-apache-solr-admin-panel).
I have removed the lines

```
ProxyRequests           Off
ProxyPreserveHost       On
```

after testing them with no success upon suggestion they were no longer needed.

Unfortunately when I try to access solr.mydomain.org from the web I am timed out. Can someone point me to the right direction?

EDIT:
The code is working almost properly (no http to https redirect) once I fixed an error in my host file! I'm not sure if this should be removed or if it can be of any help.

EDIT 2:
Fixed code for redirect, now it is really stupid me!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName solr.mydomain.org
Redirect permanent / https://solr.mydomain.org
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName solr.mydomain.org
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.solr.log
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8984/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8984/
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "*it is reacheable with my ip at port 8984*" do you mean `http://localhost:8984/` ?

Comment: I mean that using the external IP of the server `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8984` I can reach it.

Comment: It seems I am having some huge problem with my apache configuration since only three of my virtualhost are actually responding and all the other are timed out... so it may be a totally different problem!